# How can I set the each line color or width in SVG path

Tags: svg, d3.js

I use the path to crate a Triangle,

```
svg.append("path").attr("d","M " + x(0) + "," + y(0) + " L " + x(1) + "," + y(1) + " " + x(-1) + "," + y(1) + " " + x(0) + "," + y(0) ).style({
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1,
    fill: 'red'
});
```

How can I set the stroke color or width for each line?

thanks.

Comment: You'll have to create separate `path` elements.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @Lars said, you need to use separate path elements. Also, you could use a line generator so you don't have to create the path strings by hand.

```
var data = [
    {p: [{x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 100}], w: 2, c: 'red'},
    {p: [{x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 150, y: 200}], w: 3, c: 'blue'},
    {p: [{x: 150, y: 200}, {x: 200, y: 100}], w: 1, c: 'green'}
];

// Line generator
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

svg.selectAll('path')
   .data(data)
   .enter().append('path')
   .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.p); })
   .attr('stroke-width', function(d) { return d.w; })
   .attr('stroke', function(d) { return d.c; });
```

I wrote a small fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/9Qqy8/

Comment: So the next I should draw the other Triangle behind this to fill the color?

Comment: I would recommend to create the filled triangle behind the lines, so the triangle don't hide the lines. Consider accepting the question if it solved your problem, so the community can know that it was answered.