# Efficient way to color an SVG path with differing colors (not a gradient)

Tags: javascript, r, svg

I want to draw an `svg` path using a varying series of colors.  The list of colors is limited, but it is not a gradient, it is derived from values external to the path/line.  In `R` I do it this way, as a series of segments and an associated vector of colors.  There are a lot of data points (thousands), so even though the color may change abruptly for each segment the effect is smooth:

```
# Color scale for each level
# blue/low -> red/high, anchored at zero (index 5, a shade of green)
# max and min will come from the data (i.e., red will be at max of V)
cscale <- c(rev(rainbow(4, start = 0.45, end = 0.66)),
  rev(rainbow(5, start = 0.0, end = 0.25)))
# view with:
# pie(rep(1, 9), col = cscale)

refscale <- seq(-1, 1, length.out = 9)  
myc <- cscale[findInterval(C[row,], refscale)] # C is a correlation matrix, values -1 ... 1

np <- length(spectra$freq)
ind1 <- 1:(np-1)
ind2 <- 2:np

plot(spectra$freq, V[row,], type = "n") # V is a covariance matrix, values -Inf ... Inf
segments(spectra$freq[ind1], V[row, ind1], spectra$freq[ind2], V[row, ind2],  col = myc, ...)
```

Which gives a figure like this (EDIT: added detailed view):

[image: gradient] [image]

I want to do this in `JavaScript`.  I see that there are several ways to apply a gradient to a stroke but that is not what I need.  In my case, each line segment needs its own color.  Any suggestions about how to accomplish this efficiently in `js`?  I could loop over the segments individually and draw them one at a time each with their own color, but that sounds very slow (I haven't tried it, maybe it's faster than I imagine).  I have working `js` code that draws the line in black or whatever.  I wish I could just pass a vector of colors to the stroke attribute but that's not the `js` way.  Is there a trick I am missing to do this?

EDIT: I am drawing the line using `d3.svg.line`.

EDIT2: Upon further research, I was inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266535/633251) which led me to ask from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30314460/633251) somewhat different perspective.  There are two good complete answers there.

Answer (score 4):

If these are all functions that you're charting (one x value -> one y value) then technically, you can do this with a filter, but it's probably more work that it's worth, and canvas is a better option. But if you really want to stay in d3 and you really want a single line object for whatever reason, then you can get there by creating a color mask that lines up with the line segments and compositing it with your line. (This doesn't work in Firefox - you need to inline the colormask as a data URI within the feImage in order to get cross-browser). Example:

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <defs>
    
    <g id="colormask">
      <rect  x="0" y="0" height="600" width="50" fill="red"   stroke="none" />
      <rect  x="50" y="0" height="600" width="20" fill="blue"  stroke="none"   />
      <rect  x="70" y="0" height="600" width="50" fill="green"    stroke="none" />
      <rect  x="120" y="0" height="600" width="30" fill="grey"  stroke="none"   />
      <rect  x="150" y="0" height="600" width="15" fill="black" stroke="none"   />
      <rect  x="165" y="0" height="600" width="50" fill="blue"   stroke="none"  />
      <rect  x="215" y="0" height="600" width="20" fill="cyan"  stroke="none"   />
      <rect  x="235" y="0" height="600" width="50" fill="red"   stroke="none"  />
      <rect  x="285" y="0" height="600" width="30" fill="pink"  stroke="none"   /> 
      <rect  x="315" y="0" height="600" width="15" fill="magenta" stroke="none" />
      <rect  x="330" y="0" height="600" width="50" fill="yellow"   stroke="none"/>
      <rect  x="380" y="0" height="600" width="20" fill="purple"   stroke="none"/>
      <rect  x="400" y="0" height="600" width="50" fill="red"   stroke="none"  />
      <rect  x="450" y="0" height="600" width="30" fill="blue"  stroke="none"  /> 
      <rect  x="480" y="0" height="600" width="50" fill="pink"   stroke="none" />
      <rect  x="530" y="0" height="600" width="15" fill="grey" stroke="none"  />
    </g>
      
    <filter id="colorline" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="600" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <feImage xlink:href="#colormask" result="mask1"/>
      <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" in="mask1" operator="in" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <path filter="url(#colorline)" d="M0 50 l50,30 20,-15 50,-40 30,20 15,40 50,30 20,-15 50,-40 30,20 15,40 50,30 20,-15 50,-40 30,20 15,40 50,30 20,-15 50,-40 30,20 15,40 50,30 20,-15 50,-40 30,20 15,40 " fill="none " stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: There is a problem with your example. You have two elements with id "colormask". This is going to be unreliable.  It seems to work ok in Chrome, but does in FF.

Comment: Thanks Paul - fixed the ID's - and filed a bug against Chrome for positioned floods - it's a recent regression

Answer (score 1):

For the requirements as witten, canvas may be a better fit than SVG.

If you do want to proceed with SVG, draw a single `<path>` element encompassing all the segments of a single colour. [M or m](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands) commands in the path can be used to create discontinuous segments and [L or l](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataLinetoCommands) can create the lines.

Comment: Exactly how I did it on thousands of data points.

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to either:

1. Draw a series of `<line>` elements. One for each data point.  This should be okay as long as there are not a ridiculous number of them.
2. You could make it a bit more efficient by using a `<polyline>` and keep all the points of one colour together.

Comment: A `<path>` would be required rather than a `<polyline>` as the points of one colour will not be contiguous will they?

Comment: It's hard to tell from such a tiny image, but if you zoom in, it does look like a line graph rather than something like a bar graph.  At least that was what I assumed.  Near the end it looks like there are at least 5 or 6 red lines in a sequence.

Comment: I added a more detailed image.  I'm currently drawing the line with `d3.svg.line`.  I guess one option both answers have suggested is to sort by color and then draw in chunks.  That would be faster than looping over every segment.  Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @RobertLongson It's not completely clear from either image (sorry) but the x dimension is evenly spaced and quite close together (see the dark blue in the detailed image).  So, there are some contiguous elements of the same color but not a lot.  From plot to plot there are no guarantees of any pattern for the color.