# Using a function to return a series of colors for stroke

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need help fine-tuning a function to return a series of colors to go with a series of x,y pairs to create a multicolored line.  Here is a MWE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"> </script>
</body>

<script>

var margin = {top: 100, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xdata = d3.range(0, 10);
var ydata = [1, 12, 5, 9, 10, 14, 6, 15, 11, 10];
var colorvec = ["#00FFB3", "#80FF00", "#00E0FF", "#0075FF", "#00FFB3", "#00FFB3", "#80FF00", "#00E0FF", "#00FFB3", "#80FF00"]

var xyc = [];
for(var i = 0; i < xdata.length; i++ ) {
   xyc.push({x: xdata[i], y: ydata[i], col: colorvec[i]});
}

var xscl = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(xyc, function(d) {return d.x;}))
    .range([margin.left, width + margin.left])

var yscl = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(xyc, function(d) {return d.y;}))
    .range([height + margin.top, margin.top])

var myline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xscl(d.x);})
  .y(function(d) { return yscl(d.y);})

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height",window.innerHeight)

svg.append('rect') // outline for reference
    .attr({x: margin.left, y: margin.top,
           width: width,
           height: height,
           stroke: "black",
           'stroke-width': 0.5,
           fill:'white'});

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", myline(xyc))
    .style("fill", "none")
    // .style("stroke",  function() { return "red"; }) // works fine but trivial
    // .style("stroke",  function(d) { return xyc[0].col; }) // returns 1 col
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {return d[i].col;}}) // help here!
    .style("stroke-width", 2);

</script>
```

How can I modify the function near the end which controls the stroke so that each color in `myc` is used sequentially for the segments, creating a multicolored line?  I believe that `myc` is an array of objects and I want to get access to just the colors stored in "col".  As is, the return value is undefined.

Comment: Are you looking for a gradient or for each line segment (from point to point) to be a different color?

Comment: Each line segment should be a different color, corresponding to "col" in `myc`.  I suppose I have one more color than is needed too... Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution here would be to create 9 different lines each with their own color.  That's no fun, though, (and doesn't take advantage of the `d3` line generator) so let's see what we can do with gradients.  `d3`ifying the double stop coolness in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335354/filling-an-svg-path-with-multiple-colors):

```
// create a def
var grade = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "myGrade");

// add the gradient for each segment
colorvec.forEach(function(d, i) {
  grade.append("stop")
    .style("stop-color", d)
    .style("stop-opacity", 1)
    .attr("offset", i / (colorvec.length));
  grade.append("stop")
    .style("stop-color", d)
    .style("stop-opacity", 1)
    .attr("offset", (i + 1) / (colorvec.length));
});

...

// apply the gradient
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", myline(xyc))
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "url(#myGrade)")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnCyFNCzRXFxQqIXb56R?p=preview).

**Note**, I removed one of your colors, for 10 points we have 9 segments.

**Also note**, that this only works if the x values are equally spaced.

---

Here's the alternative, a path for each line segment:

```
  var abc = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < xdata.length-1; i++) {
    abc.push({
      p: [{x:xdata[i],y:ydata[i]}, {x:xdata[i+1],y: ydata[i+1]}],
      col: colorvec[i]
    });
  }

  svg2.selectAll('.segment')
   .data(abc)
   .enter().append('path')
   .attr('class','segment')
   .attr('d', function(d) { return myline(d.p); })
   .attr('stroke-width', 2)
   .attr('stroke', function(d) { return d.col; });
```

Example updated [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnCyFNCzRXFxQqIXb56R?p=preview).

The limitation of this, though, is you won't be able to use [interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate) since it's now 9 separate paths.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm going to need to study this a bit, it's unfamiliar territory.  In the real example there could be 10,000 data points.  I was originally inspired by this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20266535/633251) which seems to have a simple solution, but uses a very different data structure.

Comment: My understanding of many aspects of `js` is primitive.  The page I am making has brushing to zoom in.  When would `colorvec.forEach` be evaluated - once during original page loading, or would it be evaluated when zooming in?

Comment: @BryanHanson, the question you link to separates the data into multiple segments.  It would also work, but you'd have to manage your data a little bit differently.  I'll code it up, give me a few seconds.  Generally when you zoom with d3, you aren't redrawing.  So, yes, this would only be evaluated once.

Comment: Thanks so much for the alternate example - I can learn a lot from both of these.  I already put the first version into my code and it runs fast enough, but I'm going to study the 2nd one in detail - I don't grok some of the `js` data structures all that well, but a one-to-one correspondence between segments and colors is easy enough.  Thanks again, you are very generous with your time!

Comment: @BryanHanson, with 10,000 data points I would expect the first solution to be more performant.  The second will create 9,999 paths (each a part of the brower's DOM) which will be very memory intensive.