# How to set d3 stroke width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

At the moment the following draws two lines, but I can't seem to change the width:

```
var a = [23,50];
for (b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
  var stripe = vis.selectAll("line.stripep")
    .data(connections.filter(function(d,i) { return i == a[b];  }))
    .enter().append("svg:line")
      .attr("class", "stripe")
      .attr("stroke", function(d) { return "#000000"; })
      .attr("stroke-linecap", 'round')
      .attr("stroke-width", 500)
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.station1.longitude); })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d.station1.latitude); })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.station2.longitude); })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.station2.latitude); })
}
```

I want to set the width of the two black lines to 500.

At the moment I am trying:

```
.attr("stroke-width", 500)
```

I have also tried:

```
.attr("stroke-width",  function(d) { return "500"; })
```

This also did not work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Usually, painting on canvas, it is named StrokeWidth (no dash). Could that be it?

Comment: afraid not, still no change

Comment: .attr("stroke-width",  function(d) { return "500"; }) instead try 
.attr("stroke-width",  function(d) { return 500; }) without string

Comment: Try changing the value of `stroke` to `#000000`.

Comment: Well, I'm unable to help you then. Over at w3c schools, they suggest stroke-width for a path, but you're doing it on a line here, so I'm not sure if those are compatible.

Comment: @stallion that didn't work

Comment: hmm then check this link .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266112/how-can-i-set-the-each-line-color-or-width-in-svg-path

Comment: You are correct, it's "stroke-width", like this:. attr("stroke-width", number). But 500 pixels is a lot! Try small numbers first.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. Solution: I found a `.path` entry within my CSS file with a `'stroke-width'` setting.  CSS has priority :-)

Comment: good, i cant remember my solution and i wished id posted it when i had the chance.

Answer (score 1):

Change .attr to .style, and it should work

.style("stroke-width",  function(d) { return "500"; })